# How to save value form html input field in array. And after use this array

Tags: javascript

I need to store value from input in array and after that, use it. Help please =)

```
<body>
  <p></p>
  <form>
    <label for="cr"> <input type="number" id ='cr'> </label>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

const inputCr = document.querySelector('#cr');

const btn = document.querySelector('button');

  let allCr = [];

const calculate = function(){
  const valueC = Number(inputCr.value);
  allCr.push(valueC);
}
btn.addEventListener('click', calculate());
```

Comment: You are on the right path, but why do you want to put it in an array?

Comment: Why do you say you can't use your array ? I'm not sure to understand what is giving you trouble.

Comment: @ArrowHead Beacuse, there will be at list 5 values, that i needed to add one to another and after calculate sum of the value )

Comment: change the event lister part to btn.addEventListener('click', calculate);

Answer (score 1):

The problem I can see with your code is the way you pass calculate function to the event listener.

Change

```
btn.addEventListener('click', calculate());
```

to:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', calculate);
```

Still not sure why you need the array, but this will get you started :)

Comment: It works, but after I put some value, it appears in a second and then gone.